# How to flatten a column in DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataframe with this format:

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "elements": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "a"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "b"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "c"
    }]
}
```

We can flatten the columns like this:

```
val exploded = df.withColumn("elements", explode($"elements"))
exploded.show()
 >> +--------+------+------+
 >> |elements|field1|field2|
 >> +--------+------+------+
 >> |   [1,a]|value1|value2|
 >> |   [2,b]|value1|value2|
 >> |   [3,c]|value1|value2|
 >> +--------+------+------+
val flattened = exploded.select("elements.*", "field1", "field2")
flattened.show()
 >> +---+----+------+------+
 >> | id|name|field1|field2|
 >> +---+----+------+------+
 >> |  1|   a|value1|value2|
 >> |  2|   b|value1|value2|
 >> |  3|   c|value1|value2|
 >> +---+----+------+------+
```

Is there a way to get the flattened dataframe without explicitly specifying the remaining columns? Something like this (although this doesn't work)?

```
val flattened = exploded.select("elements.*", "*")
```

Comment: `exploded.select("elements.*", "*")` works just fine in any supported version, though you probably want `exploded.select("elements.*", "*").drop("elements")`.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can query the columns of `exploded`, then select all except `elements`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val colsToSelect = exploded.columns.filterNot(c => c == "elements").map(col)

val flattened = exploded.select(($"elements.*" +:colsToSelect):_*)
```